# I am trying to add a drop shadow to a UImageView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, dropshadow

I am trying to add a drop shadow to a UIImage view. I get a shadow but it is clipped to the edges of the image view and I am not sure why since I correctly set the uiimageview.clipsToBounds to NO. Below is the code:

```
-(void)addShadow
{
   UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.frame.size);
   CGContextRef myContext =  UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
   float           myColorValues[] = {0, 0, 0, darkness};// 3
   CGColorRef      myColor;// 4
   CGColorSpaceRef myColorSpace;
   CGContextSaveGState(myContext);// 6

   myColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB ();// 9
   myColor = CGColorCreate (myColorSpace, myColorValues);// 10
   CGContextSetShadowWithColor (myContext, myShadowOffset, spread, myColor);// 11
   // Your drawing code here// 12
   // CGContextDrawImage(myContext, rotatingView.frame,imgRef);

   rotatingView.clipsToBounds = NO;
   [rotatingView.image drawInRect:rotatingView.frame
                        blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:.5];
   CGColorRelease (myColor);// 13
   CGColorSpaceRelease (myColorSpace); // 14

   UIImage *imageCopy = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
   CGContextRestoreGState(myContext);
   UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
   rotatingView.image = imageCopy;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the CGContextRef you're passed also has clipping set, to prevent basically this exact behavior. You might want to try just adding a CALayer:

```
CALayer                         *layer = [CALayer layer];
CGRect                          bounds = self.bounds;

layer.bounds = bounds;
layer.position = CGPointMake(bounds.size.width / 2 + 5, bounds.size.height / 2 + 5);
layer.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite: 0.10 alpha: 0.75].CGColor;
layer.zPosition = -5;

[self.layer addSublayer: layer];
```

Comment: I tried adding this code but I still end up with clipped shadows.

Comment: Am I doing something else wrong in adding the code as above? or is the layer suppose to be the shadow?

Comment: The layer is supposed to be the shadow. You did set clipsToBounds to NO still?

Comment: Ah I see. clipstobounds is set to no. The problem with the layer is that it produces a square shadow with no blue, under a UIImage with any given shape. I was trying to apply the shadow directly to the UIImage.

Comment: ah, there's no easy way to do this. You'll basically have to do a custom shadow, and while there are several ways to do it, none of 'em are trivial to implement.

Comment: make sure you #import "QuartzCore/CALayer.h"