# border in UIImageView

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, objective-c++

I am trying to have an UIImageView bordered like the following:

[image]

I have tried using:

```
[imageView.layer setBorderColor: [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
[imageView.layer setBorderWidth: 2.0];
```

but then you can't see that gray border on the outside. It has that gray shadow effect on the outside.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at the shadow properties of CALayer.

```
[imageView.layer setShadowOffset:CGSizeMake(-1.0, -1.0)];
[imageView.layer setShadowOpacity:0.5];
```

Answer (score 2):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044479/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-a-shadow-behind-a-uiimageview) about adding shadows to UIImageView might help

Answer (score 2):

```
imageView.layer.shadowOpacity=0.6;
imageView.layer.shadowRadius = 0.0;
imageView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
imageView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-2.0, 1.0);
```