# how do I do a page curl effect on two corners of an image

Tags: objective-c, ios, user-interface, effects, page-curl

[image]

I'm trying to do the effect shown above in my app, but am unsure what the best practices are.  The effect I want is the curled bottom corners of the outer picture frame.

Is it better to:

1. use a page curling library like: [XBPageCurl](https://github.com/xissburg/XBPageCurl)
2. use images
3. use some other effect

Comment: This is not exactly curl. For that effect you should probably use Arc/Path drawing with shadow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Curled View Category for iOS: http://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/curledviews-category

Comment: This a great start, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use shadow images just like [these](http://graphicriver.net/item/32-realistic-modern-web-shadows/152144).

Comment: I agree, if you just want a "shadow" affect as shown, it's probably best just to use an image. If you're doing this on images created say from a photo taken by the user, you might look into programmatic solutions (perhaps using `QuartzCore`? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044479/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-a-shadow-behind-a-uiimageview )... but there will be a memory and computation cost for this, so use sparingly...

Comment: You can stretch shadow image to fit dynamic image. In any case, if you were not using shadow images, you should limit minimum and maximum image size. So shadow will fit that limited sized image.