# Tracing UIBezierPath from transparent Image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibezierpath, cgpath

I was wondering if there was a way to analyse a transparent UIImage outline and create a UIBeizerPath to create a Drop Shadow.

Similar to the way the UITabBar will create a drop shadow around the outline of your Tab Bar image.

[image]

Comment: Do you need the UIBezierPath for other purposes? Or do you just need a drop shadow, perhaps [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2044479/what-is-the-best-way-to-create-a-shadow-behind-a-uiimageview) has your answer.

Comment: Other purposes also, but that is a good start. Can I extract a UIBeizerPath from a UIImageView?

Comment: I'm not going to say it is not possible, but it is a very complex problem. Basically what you are trying to do is to get a vector shape from rasterised bitmap image. You would need to do quite a lot of mathematics and image processing to achieve this. But you can do it manually :) http://www.sketchcasts.net/episodes/how-to-get-a-vector-shape-from-a-bitmap-image

Comment: The iOS SDK doesn't include shape tracing.  You'll need to find a third-party library or implement it yourself.