# How to create drop shadows programmatically?

Tags: iphone, dropshadow

In one iPhone app, I'd like to add drop shadows to a few icons dynamically (the angle of the shadow is not fixed). Is there any built-in API for this purpose? If not, how can this be done? Thanks!

Comment: How are you displaying your icons?

Comment: You may wish to refer to these similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1943087/i-am-trying-to-add-a-drop-shadow-to-a-uimageview and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/962827/uiimage-shadow